# Add two arrays by elements

Tags: c

```
{0, 0, 0, 1} + {5} = {5, 0, 0, 1}
```

I want to add elements of these arrays the way I described it above in ONE LOOP. How can I do this? I can come up only with the following solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   outcomes = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Where a and b are the first arrays, and "outcome" is the array of outcomes. But this will break execution of the program as the arrays are not of the same size.

Comment: use the length of the smaller array in the for loop as in
 for(int i=0;i<shortArray.Length;i++)... shortArray in your example is is the second one

Answer (score 2):

1. find  length of both arrays .
2. Create  "outcomes" array of the length of longer array copy content of longer array to it.

`

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(smaller_array_length); i++)       
    { 

            outcomes[i] = a[i] + b[i]; 

    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Copy the longer of the two list to your outcome list (can be omitted if you can overwrite the longer list) and then iterate through the shorter list and add the values. In the following, I assume that `a` is longer than `b`:

```
memcpy(outcomes, a, LEN_A * sizeof(TYPE_OF_LIST_ELEMENTS);
for (i = 0; i < LEN_B; i++)
    outcomes[i] += b[i];
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you. Surely will be useful in the future, but I need to do this one by one from the first index however - homework requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Loop based on the size of the result that you want, and then test to deal with that being longer than either (or both) inputs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH(outcomes); i++) {
    if (i < LENGTH(a)) {
        if (i < LENGTH(b) {
            outcomes[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        } else {
            outcomes[i] = a[i];
        }
    } else {
        if (i < LENGTH(b) {
            outcomes[i] = b[i];
        } else {
            outcomes[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can leave out some of the cases if you know they can't occur -- so if `LENGTH(outcomes) == max(LENGTH(a), LENGTH(b))`, you don't need the last `else`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define c2d(c) (c-'0')
#define d2c(c) (c+'0')

char* add(char *a, char *b){
    int alen, blen;
    int i, carry=0;
    char *wk;

    alen=strlen(a);
    blen=strlen(b);
    if(alen<blen){
        alen ^= blen;blen ^= alen;alen ^= blen;//swap
        wk = a ; a = b ; b = wk;
    }
    wk = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(alen+2));
    wk[alen+1]=wk[alen]='\0';
    for(i=0;i<alen;++i){
        int sum = c2d(a[i])+(i<blen ? c2d(b[i]): 0)+carry;
        wk[i] = d2c(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
    }
    if(carry){
        wk[i++]='1';
    }
    return wk;
}

int main(){
    char *a1="0001";
    char *a2="5";
    char *a3="99";
    char *a4="02";
    char *a5="51";
    printf("{%s}+{%s}={%s}\n", a1, a2, add(a1,a2));
    printf("{%s}+{%s}={%s}\n", a2, a1, add(a2,a1));
    printf("{%s}+{%s}={%s}\n", a3, a3, add(a3,a3));
    printf("{%s}+{%s}={%s}\n", a4, a5, add(a4,a5));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First copy the values of the long array into the outcome array and then do

```
for(int i = 0; i < shortArrayLength; i++)
    {
       outcomes[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
```

Comment: pass the short array length

Comment: I would still have the rest of the longer array left.

Comment: Still your code is not working as you wrote it, it would not copy all the values of the longer array in the outcome array.